# How can I dynamically "bind" a class to a different xaml?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Let's say I want to switCh between 2 UserControls programmatically:

- one UserControl contains a TextBox with a label
- the other contains only TextBox

I'd like a single codebehind. Is it possible ? if yes how ? If not how to do the above requirement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have two usercontrols acting similar and you don't want to write the code-behind double?

Create a ViewModel for the controls. Use for both of the controls the same ViewModel. Look at the [MVVM-Pattern](http://hugeonion.com/2009/03/08/wpf-mvvm-video-by-jason-dolinger/).

Another possibility would be to create a [CustomControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) and make two templates.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have one usercontrol and switch the Visibility of the Label using a style trigger based on some property of the datacontext?

Comment: Well because it's a contrived example in real I may need more than just hiding :)